# Regular expression to identify all numerics, across all localization formats

Tags: java, regex

I'm scanning a text with a Scanner object, let's say `lineScanner`. Here are the declarations:

```
String myText= "200,00/100,00/28/65.36/21/458,696/25.125/4.23/6.3/4,2/659845/4524/456,65/45/23.495.254,3";
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(myText);
```

With that `Scanner`, I would like to find the first `BigDecimal`, and after the second one, and so on. I declared a `BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN` to match any case.

Here are the rules I defined:

- Thousands separator is always followed by exactly 3 digits
- There is always exactly 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point.
- If the thousands separator is the comma symbol, so the decimal point is the dot symbol and conversely
- Thousands separator is optional, as decimal part of the number

---

```
String nextBigDecimal = lineScanner.findInLine(BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN);
```

Now, here is the `BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN` I declared:

```
private final String BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN=
      "\\d+(\\054\\d{3}+)?(\\056\\d{1,2}+)?|\\d+(\\056\\d{3}+)?(\\054\\d{1,2}+)?)";
```

`\\054` is the ASCII octal representation of `","`

`\\056` is the ASCII octal representation of `"."`

My problem is that it doesn't work well because when the pattern of the first part is found, the second part (after the `|`) is not checked and in my example
the first match will be `200` and not `200,00`. So I can try this:

```
private final String BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN=\\d+([.,]\\d{3}+)?([,.]\\d{1,2}+)?
```

But there is a new problem: comma and dot are not exclusive, I mean if one is the thousands separator, the decimal point should be the other one.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Note that this is not across "all localization format". IIRC, India has different way of splitting the digits.

Comment: ("Thousands" separator not always is three digits.) If one text is in one locale only: to parse as decisively as possible, it is better to iterate through some selected locales, and try every locale separately.

Comment: @Jonathan Did any of the answers below help to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Could you do an either-or regular expression? E.g. something like:

```
private final String BIG_DECIMAL_PATTERN
    = "\\d+((\\.\\d{3}+)?(,\\d{1,2}+)?|(,\\d{3}+)?(\\.\\d{1,2}+)?)"
```

Note - I haven't checked whether your regex actually works - and suspect this may not be the best way of achieving what you are trying to do. All I'm doing here to get you up and running is suggesting you could try using `(regex1|regex2)` where `regex1` is dots followed by commas and `regex2` is commas followed by dots.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a variant of your 2nd RegEx will work for you. Consider this regex:

```
^\\d+(?:([.,])\\d{3})*(?:(?!\\1)[.,]\\d{1,2})?$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/vHlEdBMhO9

**Explanation:** What it does is to first capture the comma or dot in capture group # 1. And then later makes sure same capture group # 1 doesn't appear at decimal point using negative lookahead. Which in other words ensures that if comma comes first then dot will come later and viceversa.